# Not getting onclick event to fire from programmatically built table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that is programmatically added with an onclick event that calls a specific javascript function with the id of the row I want to edit.  However it is not called.  I have tried changing the button by adding a class and trying to get something there but it does not work.  This used to work and I cannot figure out why or how to fix it.

```
function buildTable() {
$.ajax({
    url: "getTable.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        if (result != null) {
            $('#measurements tbody tr').remove();
            result.forEach(function (measurement) {
                var message = "<tr><td>" + dateFromtimestamp(measurement.weigh_date) + "</td>";;
                message += "<td>" + measurement.weight + "</td>";
                message += "<td><input type='hidden' value='" + measurement.id + "'>" + measurement.waist + "</td>";
                message += "<td>" + measurement.upperBp + "</td>";
                message += "<td>" + measurement.lowerBp + "</td>";
                message += "<td>" + measurement.comment + "</td>";
                message += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-warning' onlick='editRow(" + measurement.id + ")'>";
                message += "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button>&nbsp;";
                message += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-danger' onlick='removeRow(" + measurement.id + ")'>";
                message += "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button></td></tr>";
                $('#measurements').append(message);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

}

The following is the HTML table it is being added to:

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading text-center">Past measurements</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="measurements">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Weight</th>
        <th scope="col">Waist</th>
        <th scope="col">Systolic (Upper)</th>
        <th scope="col">Diastolic (Lower)</th>
        <th scope="col">Comment</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
    </tbody>
     </table>
     <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

This is the edit function in question just in case I miss something with the argument signature:

```
function editRow(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "getMeasurement.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            "id": id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != null) {
            data.forEach(function(result){
                var id = result.id;
                $('#editMeasurement').modal('show');
                $('#editupper').val(result.upperBp);
                $('#editlower').val(result.lowerBp);
                    $('#editwaist').val(result.waist);
                    $('#editweight').val(result.weight);
                    $('#editcomment').text(result.comment);
                    $('#editRowHidden').val(id);
        });             
    }
    }   
});
}
```

I have tried changing the button by adding a class:
 and trying to catch the event with $('.editRow').on("click", function() {} event with the same results.

Comment: Man I love to lick my screen to make things work.

Comment: You have a typo ` onlick='editRow`

Comment: Also, if `measurement.id` is not solely numeric, this will not work, since you are not quoting the value when passing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo `onlick` instead of `onclick`.

Also, you could consider to use passive event listener as:

```
$(document).on("click", <target>,<your function>});
```

where `<target>` is the jquery selector for you button
and `<your function>` your callback.

This would increase readability and as well helps to keep the separation between HTML and JS. And also work for dynamically inserted targets.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to kmgt.  If it was a snake it would have bit me.  Have to use 'onclick' instead of 'onlick'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I agree with @dmitrii-g that you should use [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to be able to handle any events on elements, that were added after DOM was rendered. (added dynamically). After that you should try to debug/print to console any information needed to ensure that you are passing correct values into your function. I've prepared sample example which will demonstrate this approach:

```js
const result = [{
    weigh_date: '01/01/2019',
    weight: '200lbs',
    id: 1,
    waist: 'waist',
    upperBp: 'upperBp',
    lowerBp: 'lowerBp',
    comment: 'comment'
  },
  {
    weigh_date: '01/01/2015',
    weight: '100lbs',
    id: 2,
    waist: 'waist',
    upperBp: 'upperBp',
    lowerBp: 'lowerBp',
    comment: 'comment'
  }
];

function buildTable() {
  if (result != null) {
    $('#measurements tbody tr').remove();
    result.forEach(function(measurement) {
      var message = "<tr><td>" + measurement.weigh_date + "</td>";
      message += "<td>" + measurement.weight + "</td>";
      message += "<td><input type='hidden' value='" + measurement.id + "'>" + measurement.waist + "</td>";
      message += "<td>" + measurement.upperBp + "</td>";
      message += "<td>" + measurement.lowerBp + "</td>";
      message += "<td>" + measurement.comment + "</td>";
      message += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-edit btn-outline-warning' id='" + measurement.id + "'>Edit</button>&nbsp;";
      message += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-delete btn-outline-danger' id='" + measurement.id + "'>Remove</button></td></tr>";
      $('#measurements').append(message);
    });
  }
}

$('#measurements').on('click', '.btn-edit', function() {
 const id = $(this).attr('id');
 
 console.log('ID to be edited: ' + id);
  // your stuff here
});


$('#measurements').on('click', '.btn-delete', function() {
 const id = $(this).attr('id');
 
 console.log('ID to be deleted: ' + id);
    // your stuff here
});


buildTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading text-center">Past measurements</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="measurements">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Weight</th>
        <th scope="col">Waist</th>
        <th scope="col">Systolic (Upper)</th>
        <th scope="col">Diastolic (Lower)</th>
        <th scope="col">Comment</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer may be far more complicated to do that simply adding the 'onclick' event when building the table.  I do use the console to make sure the correct values are passed, hence the reason I was asking why the event was not firing, not why it was firing with erroneous data.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$(document).on("click","tr",function() {
    console.log(this,"click");
});
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least few words about your code as well